# Unity3D setting velocity won't take effect immediately in OnCollisionEnter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I have a simple script to set the velocity to zero when a collision with something, but seems it won't work immediately:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveController : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    private float shootVelocity=30f;

    void Start () {

    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        if(GUI.Button(new Rect(0,0,100,100), "shoot"))
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = shootVelocity * Vector3.forward;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = Vector3.zero;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
    }

}
```

I also have made a [youtube video](https://youtu.be/wT4y7U3Trnk) to demonstrate the problem.

It's really important to make the ball stop immediately after a collision happens.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You get this problem because there is specific time step after which physics calculation takes place, you can read more about it here https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TimeManager.html

Imagine this situation, object are not colliding this frame, next frame first object moves for some distance and it is now colliding with second object, but it is already somewhere inside that object since it moves very fast, then the collision is detected but it is already too late. Sometimes if the object are very small and/or moving very fast collision doesn't get detected, because when it first check object one is before object two, when it checks second time object one is already passed object two, so no collision detected.

One way to do it is to make this time step smaller so Unity will check for collision more often, but this increases overhead, especially if you have a lot of physics calculations going around and position when sphere stops will never be perfect. What I suggest is you write your own calculation with this to work together with Unity's simulation.

I will give you example how to calculate perfect stopping position (position where two objects are just touching at one point) if object is moving always in same direction when  it is passing through other object and you are working with two sphere colliders whose radiuses in world scale you know. Let's name them radius1 and radius2, and parameter "t" that represents how much forward/backwards object needs to move to get perfect collision position.

When colision is detected you can do following calculation.

`Vector3 firstVector = transform.position-collidedObject.transform.position;
 Vector3 secondVector = direction;
 float r = radius1+radius2;`

(firstVector - secondVector*t).sqrMagnitude = r^2;

Expand your equation
[image]

or in text mode =\sqrt{2x_2^2t^2+z_2^2t^2-2x_1x_2t-2z_1x_2t-2z_1z_2t+x_1^2+2z_1^2}

Now solve for t and you will get two values, because you have two perfect collision positions for given direction (one before the second object and one after).

You get this equation
[image]
[Link to Symbolab equations](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/solve-for-equation-calculator/solve%20for%20t%2C%20%5Csqrt%7B2x_%7B2%7D%5E%7B2%7Dt%5E%7B2%7D%2Bz_%7B2%7D%5E%7B2%7Dt%5E%7B2%7D-2x_%7B1%7Dx_%7B2%7Dt-2z_%7B1%7Dx_%7B2%7Dt-2z_%7B1%7Dz_%7B2%7Dt%2Bx_%7B1%7D%5E%7B2%7D%2B2z_%7B1%7D%5E%7B2%7D%7D%3Dr)

It might look complex but you can see that there is only one difference in these two solutions for t (in that minus sign) and rest of it is same, you can split this in 3 variables to make it looks simple, this is just all focused in one equation so it looks like a lot.

Let's say now you have "t1" and "t2" with values for equation, you can now do

```
float finalT = Mathf.Abs(t1) < Mathf.Abs(t2) ? t1 : t2;
transform.position += dir*t;
```

You need to calculate all this only when collision is detected, I would also suggest to do this only when:

```
if((transform.position-collidedObject.transform.position).sqrMagnitude > (radius1+radius2 + someThresholdValue)^2)
```

So you ignore the calculation if objects are already positioned pretty nicely by Unity engine. Let me know how it goes, hope this helps!

Note: even if the object doesn't have constant direction you can approximate it by taking the last know direction and for the sake of calculation make it constant on that value. You won't get almost no difference and it solves the calculations tremendously.

Comment: thanks, Neven, I will try to understand this and try and let you know (it may take some time) one thing I have tried for sure is making fixed timestamp smaller does get a more precise position

Answer (score 0):

That's how physics work.

If the moving object has higher velocity, it would have higher momentum hence would take more time to stop.

You can try updating your code like this to make it more efficient.

```
public class MoveController : MonoBehaviour 
{

    [SerializeField]
    private float shootVelocity=30f;

    Rigidbody rb;
    void Start () 
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        if(GUI.Button(new Rect(0,0,100,100), "shoot"))
        {
            rb.velocity = shootVelocity * Vector3.forward;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        rb.isKinematic = true;  
        rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        rb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks for your answer but seems adding `rb.angularVelocity=Vect3.zero` didn't help very much :-(

Comment: that's not all that I changed, pre-fetching rigidbody reference will speed things up at micro-level. You can also try different rigidbody collision modes (discrete/continuous), increasing/decreasing mass, playing with position constraints. Look for all these options in rigidbody inspector

Comment: Hmm, do you mean by making `Rigidbody` a reserved reference then? just replace my code with yours, it seems all the same.

Comment: Always store components reference in a variable. GetComponent<> call takes some processing. And set IsKinematic first thing when it collides